# Ant: How can I perform tasks on multiple projects

Tags: java, ant

I am currently working on a project that involves many subprojects that all have the same directory structure. I would like to setup a system where I can run `ant build` and ant will go through each folder and run it's target on each of the folders.

There are multiple tasks like this besides compiling that I need to execute on each of the subprojects.

Does there already exist a method to handle this? Do I need to resort to scripting solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: You should consider using Maven builds. In my experience, ANT scripts are evil if greater than 2 pages, and really evil, when they call each other.

Comment: I've always wondered about Maven. For this case specifically, how would having Maven builds help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look here good tutorial http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200603/AntPart1.html
But in summary the [subAnt task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) should work